# Excel VBA - Run macro on Application open

Tags: vba, event-handling, excel

I've got this Design Template I want to apply to the application by default whenever it's opened. But a document needs to be open in order to apply a Design template. So I have to target some handlers whenever a new or existing workbook is opened/created.

So which approach can I take here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use the [Workbook_open](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/auto-run-macros.htm) event.  It sounded like that would be sufficient for the behavior that you want, but since you want your macros to be global, you might need to make them into an [add in](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-add-in-create.htm) for them.

Comment: Yes, I'm prepared to create an Add-in. But will the Workook_Open event trigger for both new workbooks created as well as existing ones?

Comment: @Kenny I don't believe it distinguishes between the two.

Answer (score 1):

The add-in approach is best for applying to existing workbooks.

If you're looking to have a standard design template applied to each new workbook, though, I suggest you create a template.

To do this:

1. Create a new empty workbook
2. Apply the design template
3. Save the file as Book.xlt (for Excel 2003; Book.xltx for versions 2007, 2010) in the following folder:  `%appdata%\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\`

Each time you create a new workbook (by opening Excel or hitting the "New" button), it'll be generated from this template file.

Comment: There's actually a huge flaw with this. If you put a Book.xlsx file into the XLSTART folder, yes, new documents are based on this. But if you happen to open an existing document, two Excel windows are opened. This is not wanted at all.

Comment: Such is the tradeoff - you either need to hit a button every time you create a new workbook or suffer the not-so-huge issue of having a second blank workbook open each time you launch Excel from a file. I'd personally rather deal with the blank workbook.